# How can I "display:none" to some adjacent text with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The code I need to work on looks like this:

```
    <p>
    <a href="http://foo.com/foo.html"></a>
    <a href="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/" rel="license">
    <img alt="Public Domain Mark" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/p/mark/1.0/88x31.png" style=""></a>
    <br> This work is free of known copyright restrictions... 
    </p>
```

It displays an image and then some text after the image. I need neither to display.

This works fine to get rid of the image:

```
a[rel="license"] {display:none;}
```

However, I need a way to get rid of the text after the `<br>` (and its unclosed tag if possible) and can't lose the closing `</p>` tag.

I am grabbing the HTML from a remote site and have no control over the markup there.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You only want to keep the first <a>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to hide this text using CSS, without adding a tag aground it- depending on how you're grabbing the site, your best bet would be to attempt to find `"This work is free of known copyright restrictions..."` and replace it with the same text surrounded by `<span></span>`; or simply deleting it altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I can do it with some jQuery but hoping some CSS wizards may know a trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I found it interesting. I'm wondering if it wouldn't work to fiddle with the box model of the `<p>` tag, so that you *hide* what you want to "get rid of", even though it's still there?

For instance, say I wanted to display the image, but not the non-element text following. (I realize you want to eliminate the image as well, but for demonstration purposes having some visible content inside the `<p>` is helpful.) Since I know the image is 31px tall, I might just go with something like:

```
p {
    height: 31px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Et voilà. Whether or not that would work for your specific need, I feel like we don't have enough context to determine. What you're *asking* for is to be left with an empty paragraph containing an invisible link, which absent larger context has no obvious purpose.

Come to think of it, though… if I then wanted to also hide the image, I'd just use a slight modification of your style above, and append:

```
a[rel="license"] { visibility: hidden; }
```

(You don't want to use `display: none`, as that will affect the dimensions of the `<p>` CSS box.)

This certainly has unfortunate implications for screen readers and the like, but for certain quick-and-dirty display needs it might suffice.